# Calling "click()" on checkboxes fails in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, end-to-end

in one of my test case, i have to perform a click on checkbox

i tried : -

```
var cb  = element(by.css('#port'+text));
cb.click() // failed
```

and

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(cb).click().perform();
```

is anybody face this kind of issue , is there any other workaround to do this

updated - tried with hard-coded values:

Template

```
   <input type="checkbox" style="min-width:50px;" id="port32201295-a833-45ea-8268-7c4bc0aa9887" ng-checked="port.checked" ng-disabled="port.disabled" ng-click="getSelectedPorts($event,port); 
submenu.network.minimizeMaximizePops($event)">
```

JS

```
    var cb  = element(by.css('#port32201295-a833-45ea-8268-7c4bc0aa9887'));
        cb.click() // failed(element is not visible | but element is visible have height & width) 
browser.actions().mouseMove(cb).click().perform();// nothing happens
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole code, maybe text is undefined ?

Comment: i had also tried with hard-coded value and  there is no syntax error, i am facing issue with only  check boxes

Comment: Calling .click() on a checkbox should work fine, I believe the issue here to be your selector not selecting an element. Have you tried going into the browser developer tools and executing the statement in there?

Comment: @TomNijs i have updated the question and also run  $('#port32201295-a833-45ea-8268-7c4bc0aa9887') in firebug which capture right checkbox

Comment: Could it be that an animation is taking place ( even a very short one ) right before you are trying to click the checkbox?

Comment: i have tried browser.sleep(50000) to put some wait before clicking the element , but no luck

Comment: @TomNijs same is working when i change check box in to the button, any clue ?

Comment: Is there perhaps an (invisible) element thats hovering over the checkbox?

Comment: @TomNijs finally resolve it  by remove all custom style from checkbox, we are used some sort of css to change checkbox appearance , click on this was working From UI but protractor was not able to trigger it .

Comment: Glad to hear it's resolved, perhaps answer your own question to allow people with a similar to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by removing custom styles form checkbox,in my case the real checkbox is override by  checkbox look like div , because of this element is not visible for protractor , this happens only in case of check-boxes because i am also using select2.js for select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use to click a  check box by using `element(locator).click()`

```
function setCheckBoxTo(locator, value){
    var checkbox = element(locator);
    checkbox.isChecked().then(function(selected){
        if(selected !== value){
            checkbox.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Reference [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/checkboxes-protractor-meir-shahar) [author](https://www.linkedin.com/in/meirs)